# PageSpeed Insights / Lighthouse shows the error 404 but site works fine

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, lighthouse

first time posting on Stack Overflow. Figured it's the go-to place for some help.

So, I redid my dad's website a month ago (started working on it six months back) and now I'm trying to tweak it a bit. But every time I run it through Lighthouse or PageSpeed Insights, I keep getting this error: "The page you requested could not be loaded reliably by Lighthouse. Check that you are testing the correct URL and that the server is responding appropriately to all requests. (Status code: 404)"

Site: https://pensionvoss.de/

Why is Lighthouse throwing this 404 error, and how do I fix it?

I'm scratching my head here. It says 404, like the site doesn't exist, but it's been up and running for over a decade, and the new WordPress version for about 1 1/2 months. It's working fine—I've tried different browsers, and visitors have no issues.

Comment: It takes long time to load website, at link, provided in question post. If cache plugin "wp-optimize" is used on website, it can be checked, if there is still this "error 404" in google pagespeed insights, after disabling cache plugin "wp-optimize" on website.

Comment: @Jai Indeed, I used the wp-optimize plugin and after disabling it the website loaded much faster (atleast it felt like it), but Lighthouse and PageSpeed Insights still gives me the 404 error like before.

I will keep the plugin deactivated for now, although I dont really understand why a plugin that should make the site faster actually makes the site slower.

Comment: It seems that this issue is there on homepage only. The status code "404 Not Found" is returned from server for homepage, but page is getting loaded in browser. Please check domain settings, file ".htaccess" settings on server.

Comment: @Jai You are absolutely right, I didnt even notice that... 
What exactly am I looking for in the htaccess file? The only two things that are in there is:  https://prnt.sc/dxtcIt7k_Dah

Comment: It seems that the details in file ".htaccess", provided in image link, are fine.

Comment: I researched a little and everything I found points to something in htaccess or permalink (which is connected to htaccess?)...
Only the Homepage shows 404 error. Thats so weird

Comment: @Jai I think I found the problem. I installed a Plugin to redirect any 404 Page to my Homepage with the intend that if smb goes to a wrong link that he sees the homepage. Looks like the plugin then automatically made the homepage itself to a 404 page... So dumb but atleast I found the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the issue is resolved at your end. Thanks.